# Why did UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum save a red image after rendering?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, gpuimage, core-image

I wrote a code using GPUImage2(https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2).

I confirmed that my code successfully save an image before touching a set button (Rendering a filtered image).

However, my code save a red image (same size, only red filled) after touching a set button.

My App. includes a RenderView IBOutlet and two IBActions (Set Button & Save Button).

Here is my full source code.

How can I successfully save an image after touching a set button?

```
import UIKit
import GPUImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var inputUIImage = UIImage(named: "testImage.png")
  @IBOutlet weak var renderView: RenderView!
  var pictureInput: PictureInput!
  var filterColorInversion = ColorInversion()

  @IBAction func setButtonDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
     pictureInput = PictureInput(image: inputUIImage!)
     pictureInput --> filterColorInversion --> renderView
    pictureInput.processImage()
  }

  @objc func saveImageFailedCallback(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWith error: NSError?, contextInfo context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    print("\(String(describing: error))")
  }

  @IBAction func saveButtonDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let outputImage = inputUIImage!.filterWithOperation(filterColorInversion)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputImage, self, #selector(saveImageFailedCallback(_:didFinishSavingWith:contextInfo:)), nil)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
}
```

*It shows that my code successfully save an image before touching a set button (Rendering a filtered image)*:

[image]

*It shows that my code successfully render a filtered image after touching a set button*:
[image]

*It shows that my code fails to save a filtered image after touching a set button (but same size and only filled red)*:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem!
I added an optional UIImage (tempImage) that is used to save temporarily on the memory.
When "saveButtonDown()" is called, I check whether tempImage is nil.
If it is nil, I just print an error message (No Image).
If it is not nil, it must had been initialized at "setButtonDown()".
Here is my full source code.
Thank you.

```
import UIKit
import GPUImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var inputUIImage = UIImage(named: "testImage.png")
    @IBOutlet weak var renderView: RenderView!
    var pictureInput: PictureInput!
    var filterColorInversion = ColorInversion()

    var tempImage: UIImage?

    @IBAction func setButtonDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
        pictureInput = PictureInput(image: inputUIImage!)

        tempImage = inputUIImage!.filterWithOperation(filterColorInversion)

        pictureInput --> filterColorInversion --> renderView
        pictureInput.processImage()
    }

    @objc func saveImageFailedCallback(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWith error: NSError?, contextInfo context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("\(String(describing: error))")
    }

    @IBAction func saveButtonDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (tempImage != nil) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempImage!, self, #selector(saveImageFailedCallback(_:didFinishSavingWith:contextInfo:)), nil)
        } else {
            print("No Image")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```